# How to access private json data on parent classname

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I have this situation:

```
// constans.ts
export const options = {
    sizes: ['foo', 'var']
}
```

```
// base.component.ts
class Base {
  constructor(private _options: object) {}
  public get options(): object { return this._options; }
}
```

```
// Child component
import { Base } from './base.component';
import { options } from './constants';

class Child extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super(options);
        console.log(this.options); // <-- {sizes: Array(2)}
        console.log(this.options.sizes); // <-- I CAN'T ACCESS TO .sizes
    }
}
```

Why can't I access `this.options.sizes` array but I can see on `console.log(this.options)`?

I have this error:

> TS2339: Property 'sizes' does not exist on type 'object'

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to the properties of the `options` object because you declared it of type `object`. If you use proper typing, it will be easier for typescript to help you with that:

```
export interface MyOptions {
  sizes: string[];
}

// base.component.ts
class Base {
  constructor(private _options: MyOptions) {}
  public get options(): MyOptions { return this._options; }
}

// Child component
import { Base } from './base.component';
import { options } from './constants';

class Child extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super(options);
        console.log(this.options); // <-- {sizes: Array(2)}
        console.log(this.options.sizes); // <-- now it should work
    }
}
```